# libphonenumber shows a NoClassDefFoundError during the attempt to get the object instance

Tags: java, libphonenumber

We are trying to get the libphonenumber to run in our java project.

The java project is running as a service on one of our servers.

On our local machines, we are using the following shell commands to include the libraries (please ignore the version numbers):

```
export ANT_HOME="C:\DEV\apache-ant-1.9.16"
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2"
export MAVEN_HOME="C:\DEV\apache-maven-3.8.6"
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANT_HOME}/bin:${MAVEN_HOME}/bin
export MB_API_HOME="C:\DEV\java-rest-api\api\target"
```

After we run the "ant" command, we move the result file (jar) on our server in the respective folder.

These are the 3 files that are needed for the library:

[image]

We have copied them on the server, in the respective lib folder.

Everything runs fine until the following error shows up:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil
```

This happens when it comes to the following line:

```
PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
```

We have found the following code on this website (https://www.baeldung.com/java-libphonenumber), where it is explained that this has to go to a pom-xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
    <version>8.12.10</version>
</dependency>
```

We have no clue which pom.xml they are writing about. These are the files that are being found by IntelliJ:

[image]

IntelliJ has no problems finding the classes and their methods when we type in the code window.

What else do we have to do and consider to get it to run on the server?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1 of ?**: As g00se suggested, we already have the class path mentioned in the build.xml, which looks like this:

[image]

I had the idea of removing the libphonenumber.jar from the lib folder on the server itself to see if we receive a different error. But it is still the same NoClassDefFoundError. It is as if the result file of ant has no clue about libphonenumber at all!

**Edit 2 of ?:**
I have experimented with this library on my private computer.

[image]

If I click on the run icon (1), it seems to work, as seen in (2).

However, going to the folder with the Main class (3) and running `java Main`, leads to the same error:

[image]

But then, I just copied the classes into the folder where the Main is, and the error changed:

[image]

Here is the snippet in the build.xml of my private project:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source">
    <!-- Compile the Java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="jars/libphonenumber.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

I guess I am missing the right approach here, do I?

**Edit 3 of ?:** I created a repository of my private/test project.

Here it is: https://github.com/3rc4n/libphonenumberexperiment

Comment: *we are using the following shell commands...*  Those are Unix shell commands - are you using Powershell by any chance?

Comment: *IntelliJ has no problems finding the classes and their methods when we type in the code window.* This suggests to me that it is using Maven, whereas you're attempting to us Ant. If it runs OK, it means that it has ```PhoneNumberUtil``` in its classpath. Incidentally it will be called something like libphonenumber-8.12.10.jar. Put that in your Ant classpath and you should be OK

Comment: Hi g00se, thanks for your answer. We indeed have the jar file mentioned in the class path in the build.xml, I just forgot to add it to the post due all the stress. I also edited the original post and added a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're obfuscating the names of jar files, but as a result, that hasn't really helped at all. And I don't know why you have one called 'libphonenumber.jar', without any version string

Comment: Company secrets, please ignore these. There are files without any version number attachted to their names, they work fine in our project, that's why we did not use any here. I am about to post another update.

Comment: *I am about to post another update.* OK, but please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: You're right, I will try to post code from now on. Another update in a few, I created a github repo.